# How To CountIF within Date Range

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to sum (countif) the total amount of matching items from one sheet, if they match a certain timeframe range (e.g. one week, one month, ALL) on the same sheet, to the matching item on the recall sheet.

EXAMPLE:
This is the sheet I want to collect the countif totals [let's call this SHEET 1]:
[image: Screenshot]

And this is the separate sheet [let's call it SHEET 2] collecting responses that I want to tally according to their date and equaling the value on [SHEET 1] in column A.

[image: Screenshot]

I need the SHEET 1 formula for each AREA to search say B:K on SHEET 2 and total the amount for each AREA on SHEET 1 for the last 7 days, last month and all time.

I was able to make something like this work before but now trying to piece together code and formula from multiple tutorials I am lost!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/170581/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

The [ISBETWEEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10538337) function will allow you to determine which entries fall within the date range.

```
=ISBETWEEN(E:E,TODAY()-7, TODAY())   //  Last 7 Days
=ISBETWEEN(E:E,TODAY()-30,TODAY())   //  Last 30 Days
```

###### Formula

[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) is used with [ISBETWEEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10538337) to ensure the rows fall within the date range.  Then [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) can count the occurrences of the value in `A2`

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(F:H,ISBETWEEN(E:E,TODAY()-7,TODAY())),A2)
```

Alternatively, adding [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) will make this a single-cell formula, avoiding the need to copy and paste the formula down the column.  This will allow editing the formula for all the rows in the same place.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(FILTER(F:H,ISBETWEEN(E:E,TODAY()-7,TODAY())),A2:A9))
```

[image]